# Google charts draw same chart multiple times

Tags: php, ajax, charts, modal-dialog

i'm trying to make a modal dialog in html, and when something is pressed to draw a google chart in the modal.

```
function inter(id)
{
var arr = [['Album','Vizualizari']];
$.ajax({

url: 'popular.php',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (json) {
    $.each(json,function (i ,value )
    {
      var c =[value.title, value.popular];
      arr.push(c);
    });

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

  function drawStuff() {
    google.visualization
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);

    var options = {
      title: 'Chess opening moves',
      width: 800,
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      bars: 'vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
      axes: {
        y: {
          0: { side: 'top', label: 'Percentage'} // Top x-axis.
        }
      },
      bar: { groupWidth: "100%" }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  };
}});
}
```

It worked but only on first modal. When i try to open another modal i've got the follow error :  `google.charts.load() cannot be called more than once` . How can i draw the chart using another callback, not 'setOnLoadCallback' ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your function contain these two lines :

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);
```

This is wrong. `google.charts.load()` loads the google visualization API and `setOnLoadCallback()` is executed *once* when the API has finished loading. But you do not want to show the chart when google visualization is loaded, but when the user click a button (or whatever) to show a modal. So remove `setOnLoadCallback` completely and move `load()` out to the global scope - simply call `drawStuff()` manually from the `success` handler :

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});

function inter(id) {
    var arr = [
        ['Album', 'Vizualizari']
    ];
    $.ajax({
        url: 'popular.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $.each(json, function(i, value) {
                var c = [value.title, value.popular];
                arr.push(c);
            });
            drawStuff(arr);
        })
    })

    function drawStuff(arr) {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);
        var options = {
            title: 'Chess opening moves',
            width: 800,
            legend: {
                position: 'none'
            },
            bars: 'vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
            axes: {
                y: {
                    0: {
                        side: 'top',
                        label: 'Percentage'
                    } // Top x-axis.
                }
            },
            bar: {
                groupWidth: "100%"
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
```